# Why we need to add <div id="fb-root"></div>

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

Why we need to add these pair of tags within our facebook application. What's the use of this pairs of tags. 
I created an application which use an apprequest, and it works good even if I didn't add these tags in front of my scripts.
So I really wonder why we need to add them.
Thank you.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's the place holder for the Facebook javascript script to attach elements to the DOM.  Without this when the referenced Facebook script is ran it has nowhere to attach elements.

You can see fb-root gets appended to as part of the initialisation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: 'xxxxxx', status: true, cookie: true,
                 xfbml: true});
      };

      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
```

Comment: This is an example of using unobtrusive javascript.

Comment: hi anyone notice the <div id="fb-root"></div> will cause your https:// to be unsecure?? When i directly point the browser to https://.../myfb_app/ the file isn't parse as secure if i have the <div id="fb-root"></div> but when i remove it, the whole file does parse as secure. Any suggestions??

Comment: Couldn't they directly append to head?

Comment: Couldn't they just directly append to the first body tag?

Comment: at least for the html5 version, the fb-root div should been taken off.

Comment: This is not unobtrusive. Facebook should create an element to attach it's own elements to.

Comment: The v2.1 SDK creates it for you (with a warning in the console) if not already present.

Comment: Update: The SDK no longer requires the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` tag, and there is no longer any warning in the console if the tag is omitted. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33428040/1145177).

Comment: Josh. No. See my reply to you on my answer.

Answer (score 44):

UPDATE: Facebook no longer requires that you include `<div id="fb-root"></div>` in your HTML.

You can now remove it. The Facebook Javascript SDK creates it on its own, appending it to the `BODY` tag. No warnings are shown in the console either, as it did before.

The Facebook documentation has also been updated, no longer showing the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` requirement.

Old documentation for version 1.0 (shows `<div id="fb-root"></div>`):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v1.0

Current documentation for version 2.5 (no longer shows `<div id="fb-root"></div>`): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.5

Comment: Except then we seem to have problems like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019877/fb-init-function-gives-wrong-version-error).

Comment: @mgalgs: Reading those comments, it doesn't appear that anyone found a fix for whatever was causing the OP's issue. So I wouldn't say adding the div tag is a fix for anything. If there was an issue, it's been 2 years and I'm sure it's been resolved by Facebook. The best option is to follow their code recommendations, which do not include that div tag.

Comment: @JoshM. Any warning you're receiving isn't related to this topic. Just follow the current code that Facebook recommends.

Comment: @DougS ?? It's completely related. v2.8 shows the warning if you don't include the `fb-root` div.

Comment: @JoshM. Copy-and-paste the warning here. I suspect the warning you're referring to is completely unrelated. The Facebook code has long since done away with the `div` tag.

Comment: @DougS See here (I wish I could format it better): 
facebook-sdk-debug.js:2069 The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating
@ facebook-sdk-debug.js:2069append @ facebook-sdk-debug.js:3237appendHidden 
@ facebook-sdk-debug.js:3284(anonymous function) 
@ facebook-sdk-debug.js:7321flush 
@ facebook-sdk-debug.js:3164

Comment: @JoshM. That's not a "warning". That's debug info simply stating that it's auto-creating the div tag. Again, just follow the setup instructions Facebook has provided, which has done away with hard-coding that div tag.

Comment: Seems like FB reverted this change, <div id=“fb-root”></div> does show up in the code generated by Like Button Configurator on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/#, and the button doesn't show up without this div

Answer (score -2):

It gets even more simple with Turbolinks 5. You just need to add `data-turbolinks-permanent=true` to the `fb-root` div and it will be persisted between requests. No need to fiddle with the javascript.