# Facebook open graph not working

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My script:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Meta tags

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="..
          all over Malaysia. Visit us now for Home Tuition and More!"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="content goes here"/>  
    <title>Tutor Registration: Gloopal- Home tuition and More!</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Malaysia's Best Private Tutoring Website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://[sample.com]/img/fb.png" />
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://[sample.com]/img/fb.png" /> 
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" /> 
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" /> 
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Visit [sample.com] today for the most reliable, brilliant and honest tutors from all over Malaysia! We've got you covered, for the widest ever range of subjects. We charge ZERO fees/commission for students and tutors, for all tutoring arrangements- we're one of a kind indeed!" />
      <!--open graphs ends-->
```

jquery appended html

```
<div class='fb-share-button' data-href='https://gloopal.com/index.php' data-layout='button'></div>
```

When I tried the above on [https://sample.com] it worked fine after few round of refresh on the browser.

Next I tried to share more specific posts instead of the whole website in general. So refered to a page with ID on each share button.However it simply ignored it and just showing the general website. I don't understand why I didn't get the specific page with ID and show contents of that page.

```
<div class='fb-share-button' data-href='https://gloopal.com/search2.php?TID="+ tid +"' data-layout='button'></div>
```

Now, I tried sharing back the website in general as I've created a subdomain for revamp work. In this domain the basic sharing of the button not showing the images and descriptions attached to it, let alone sharing by ID.

When I debugged in facebook debug, it shows this error:

> Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.

Then I read few questions on this learnt few tips:In order to facebook to scrape the content, must set with and height for the image. ALso, facebook doesn't show the image in the first load so must keep refreshing. Facebook also doesn't remove the previously cached content though I change them in my file. SO I need to refrech the facebook debug after placing my URL once or twice.Not just this, I l also learnt that even HTTPS can cause problem, so I even tried replacing it with http and also added secured_url on the image meta tag.

Despite all my attempts, I still can't share image and content in the facebook.If anybody knows where I lack, please also do me a favour by letting me know on how to share posts by ID which means different image,content per ID.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to re-parse the DOM. Put your button in a container with a 'fb' id, like so:

```
<div id="fb"><div class='fb-share-button' data-href='https://gloopal.com/search2.php?TID="+ tid +"' data-layout='button'></div></div>
```

Then try this just after jQuery's append

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fb'));
```

Comment: I got this error: Uncaught Error: init not called with valid version

Comment: <div id="fb-root"></div> should be in the body and not before the SDK call that might be why. You could even try to omit it altogether, the SDK will inject it on its own. [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019877/fb-init-function-gives-wrong-version-error) might help